# how do I separate the detail section of ms access report in two pages for print preview and printing?

Tags: ms-access, printing, report, ms-office

I created a report in ms access 2013 in design view that looks like a registration form with a lot of labels and textboxes. I put all the labels and textboxes in the report detail section. I want my report to be a 2 pages report. When I click the print preview option there is a message dialog that said that the report is too long for one page. So it only shows one page and the next page in blank.

When I export the report in pdf format there were 6 pages in total, blank pages in between and the second page was exported in the 4th page.

How can a create a two page report? and how can I show the whole/complete report in two pages in the print preview?

[image]

Comment: This is essentially a design, not programming, issue and question is too broad. Perhaps you can use a PageBreak control. But without knowing more about data and desired output, hard to say. What you show is not enough data to require 2 pages. I've never seen a message that report was too long, I have seen 'too wide'.

Comment: This is indeed usually caused by the report being too **wide**. Check page setup and margins; decrease report width if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how to do a two page report by placing all my textboxes and labels of my report first page on the left 7 inches of the report on the detail section. And for the second page of my report I placed all the textboxes and labels on the next 7 inches of the report leaving 2 inches spaces between them. Meaning from inches 10 to the right until inches 17. Always maintaining the height length not more than 10 inches so that we can print it on a 8 1/2 x 11 page and using the ruler as reference.